# Open the main form and go to record of the subform

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a mainform in MS Access 2010. In it are two subforms, which are linked together. One of the subs is a "single form", the other a "datasheetview". On the upper Sub, the user can see the details of the record, which is choosen in the sub below. It works fine.

I want open this Access-App from an other Access-App, open the mainform and go to a specific record. Here is the code:

```
Dim appAccess As Access.Application

Set appAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")

appAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\xxx\xxx\Desktop\MyAccess.accdb"
appAccess.DoCmd.OpenForm "subGridView", , , "[Number_X] = '" & Me.number_for_X.Value & "'"
```

It works, but I open the subform, which is below in the MAIN. I think I need something like this:

```
Dim appAccess As Access.Application

Set appAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")

appAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\xxx\xxx\Desktop\MyAccess.accdb"
appAccess.DoCmd.OpenForm "MAIN"
appAccess.DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, "subGridView", acGoTo, 37
```

37 is only a test-parameter...

Or something like:

```
Dim appAccess As Access.Application
Dim rNr As String

Set appAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
rNr = Me.number_for_X.Value

appAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\xxx\xxx\Desktop\MyAccess.accdb"
appAccess.DoCmd.OpenForm "MAIN"

Forms!subGridView.Recordset.FindFirst "[Retoure_Nummer] = '" & rNr
Set appAccess = Nothing
```

Please give me some hints :-)

Greetz Vegeta_77

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
Forms!MAIN!subGridView.Form.Recordset.FindFirst "[Retoure_Nummer] = '" & rNr & "'"
```

Where `subGridView` is not the independent name of the subform, but the name of the subform control within the main form (often the same thing but not necessarily).

Comment: you saved me mate. Thanks´!